# Visual studio 2013 console compile time and memory

Tags: compilation

I tried some things like checking Build Timing and changing output verbosity, but the compile time doesn't show anywhere for me.

Comment: What kind of projects are you trying to compile? ASFAIK build time is only shown for C# projects.

Comment: C# console applications